# PHP download script not working on centos 7

Tags: php, linux, apache, download, centos7

I'm having an issue with PHP download on CentOS 7.
Apache version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16

I'm wondering what could be the issue/any configuration that could prevent the download from working. On my local machine, this is working. I've changed the headers, done this done that and all is working very well on my local machine, but when I proceed deployment on our server, the download is not working.

Here's my code:

```
set_time_limit(0); 
ignore_user_abort(false);
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', "Off"); }
$filepath = "/var/www/creative/testdownload.pdf";
if ($fd = fopen ($filepath, "r")) {
        $fsize = filesize($filepath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($filepath);
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Expires: -1");
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Cache-Control: no-store');
        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"preview.pdf\""); 
        //header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header("Keep-Alive: close");
        header('Content-Length: '.$fsize);
        header("Accept-Length: ".$fsize);
        while (!feof($fd)) {
            echo fread($fd, 8192);
            flush(); 
            @ob_flush();
        }
    }
    fclose ($fd);
```

Comment: i don't know but it may related with chmods of the /var/www/creative/testdownload.pdf if your local machine is windows its normal. The apache user (www-data) should at least read access and execute access to the container directory like (755) Please if you can check take a look at your php errorlog file at the server.

Comment: my local machine is also centos 7, permission access is 755.. no issue on error log... the page just keeps loading and when it's stop no download is happening.. this just happens in our test server. don't know exactly what configuration that could prevent this download script from running. thanks for the help :)

Comment: Fixed some grammar & formatting errors.